# Parallel processing Flux::groupBy hangs

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor, reactive-streams

I'm using reactor 3.4.18 and have a question about Flux.groupBy. I have generated 1000 integers and splited them into 100 groups, I expect that each group could be process in sperate thread but it hangs after several integers processed.

```java
    @Test
    void shouldGroupByKeyAndProcessInParallel() {
        final Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.newParallel("group", 1000);

        StepVerifier.create(Flux.fromStream(IntStream.range(0, 1000).boxed())
                .groupBy(integer -> integer % 100)
                .flatMap(groupedFlux -> groupedFlux
                        .subscribeOn(scheduler) // this line doesn't help
                        .doOnNext(integer -> log.info("processing {}:{}", groupedFlux.key(), integer)),
                    2)
            )
            .expectNextCount(1000)
            .verifyComplete();
    }
```

test execution logs:

```
10:47:58.670 [main] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers - Using Slf4j logging framework
10:47:58.846 [group-1] INFO com.huawei.hwclouds.coney.spike.FluxGroupByTest - processing 0:0
10:47:58.866 [group-1] INFO com.huawei.hwclouds.coney.spike.FluxGroupByTest - processing 1:1
10:47:58.867 [group-1] INFO com.huawei.hwclouds.coney.spike.FluxGroupByTest - processing 0:100
10:47:58.867 [group-1] INFO com.huawei.hwclouds.coney.spike.FluxGroupByTest - processing 1:101
10:47:58.867 [group-1] INFO com.huawei.hwclouds.coney.spike.FluxGroupByTest - processing 0:200
10:47:58.867 [group-1] INFO com.huawei.hwclouds.coney.spike.FluxGroupByTest - processing 1:201
-------- start hanging ----------
```

I have changed the flatmap concurrecy to 2 to speed up the reproduction. I expects that flatmap should only slow the whole processing time but should not hang

Comment: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#groupBy-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: @Toerktumlare I have read this document before and write the test to demostrate the scenario. I am wondering why it hangs, each group flux would be eventually consumed and why it hangs instead of slow processing

Comment: if you read the documentation why havn\t you mentioned anything about `eg. due to a flatMap with a maxConcurrency parameter that is set too low`

Comment: also if you intend to use parallel (which should most likely only be used for heavy cpu intensive tasks and not i/o work) i suggest you read the section of how to use it in the docs https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#advanced-parallelizing-parralelflux